# Using regular expressions in python to extract location mentions in a sentence

Tags: python, expression, extract

I am writing a code using python to extract the name of a road,street, highway, for example a sentence like "There is an accident along Uhuru Highway", I want my code to be able to extract the name of the highway mentioned, I have written the code below.

```
sentence="there is an accident along uhuru highway"
listw=[word for word in sentence.lower().split()]
for i in range(len(listw)):
    if listw[i] == "highway":
        print listw[i-1] + " "+ listw[i]
```

I can achieve this but my code is not optimized, i am thinking of using regular expressions, any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'uhuru highway' can be found as follows

```
import re

m = re.search(r'\S+ highway', sentence)  # non-white-space followed by ' highway'
print(m.group())
# 'uhuru highway'
```

Comment: Okay. This one works. Now i have a list of words that also have an indication of location.  for example a sentence could be having road,rd,hwy,hiway,av,avenue,st,street. How do i put this list as an option for the regular expression

Comment: Use sth like: `r'\S+ (road|rd|hwy|hiway|av|avenue|st|street)'`

Comment: Thanks. What i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If the location you want to extract will always have highway after it, you can use:

```
>>> sentence = "there is an accident along uhuru highway"

>>> a = re.search(r'.* ([\w\s\d\-\_]+) highway', sentence)
>>> print(a.group(1))

>>> uhuru
```

Comment: Okay. This one works. Now i have a list of words that also have an indication of location. for example a sentence could be having road,rd,hwy,hiway,av,avenue,st,street. How do i put this list as an option for the regular expression

Comment: `re.search(r'.* ([\w\s\d\-\_]+) .*', sentence)` @leboMagma The `.*` will match anything after be highway, road, drive, street, village etc. but i would prefer @schwobaseggi method if you only have few matches

Comment: Thanks. My options are limited as suggested i will use the solution from @schwobaseggi

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following without using regexes:

```
sentence.split("highway")[0].strip().split(' ')[-1]
```

First split according to "highway". You'll get:

```
['there is an accident along uhuru', '']
```

And now you can easily extract the last word from the first part.